# Removing link from Text in Java?

Tags: java

I need to change somethign like this -> `Hello, go here http://www.google.com for your ...`
grab the link, and change it in a method i made, and replace it back into the string like this

-> `Hello, go here http://www.yahoo.com for your...`

Here is what i have so far:

```
if(Text.toLowerCase().contains("http://"))
{
    // Do stuff                 
}
else if(Text.toLowerCase().contains("https://"))
{
   // Do stuff                  
}
```

All i need to do is change the URL in the String to something different. The Url in the String will not always be http://www.google.com, so i can not just say `replace("http://www.google.com","")`

Comment: what od you mean you need two characters ?

Comment: Well, i need to remove the http:// to white space and get that string. am i correct?

Comment: I don't know about the others here, but I've no idea what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex:

```
String oldUrl = text.replaceAll(".*(https?://)www((\\.\\w+)+).*", "www$2");

text = text.replaceAll("(https?://)www(\\.\\w+)+", "$1" + traslateUrl(oldUrl));
```

Note: code changed to meet extra requirements in comments below.

Comment: View Edit. The Url in the String will not always be http://www.google.com, so i can not just say replace("http://www.google.com","")

Comment: OK - try that now then

Comment: ah, and can i just call my method like this:
text = text.replaceAll("(https?://)www(.\\w+)+", MyUrl()); ?

Comment: yes (maybe) - but tell me do you want to preserve `https` or `http`, or do you want to replace the protocol always with `http`

Comment: i want to preserve it. Thanks. And what if the link is a co.uk ?

Comment: Also, is there any way i can get that Link to a string before i replace it? I need to get the URL in order to change it in my method.

Comment: Ok, cool, is there any way i can extract that url and plug it into the method `MyUrl("Extracted String")`

Comment: Ok, nice. How does that extract the old URL. Could you exapain in your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can grab the link from the string using below code. I assumed the string will contain only .com domain

```
            String input = "Hello, go here http://www.google.com";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("http[s]{0,1}://www.[a-z-]*.com");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            String str = m.group();
        }
```

Comment: At some point, there might be a .co.uk , that was also one of the hard things about getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
s= s.replaceFirst("http:.+[ ]", new link);
```

This will find any word beginning with http up till the first white space and replace it with whatever you want

if you want to keep the link then you can do:

```
String oldURL;
if (s.contains("http")) {
    String[] words = s.split(" ");
    for (String word: words) {
        if (word.contains("http")) {
            oldURL = word;  
            break;
        }
    }
    //then replace the url or whatever
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but need to get the URL into a string first so i can plug it into my Method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
private String removeUrl(String commentstr)
    {
        String urlPattern = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|Unsure|http):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(commentstr);
        int i = 0;
        while (m.find()) {
            commentstr = commentstr.replaceAll(m.group(i),"").trim();
            i++;
        }
        return commentstr;
    }
```

Comment: `.replaceAll(` must replace by `.replace(`